# turning categorical data with 'from … to …' fields into a useable graph

Tags: graph, date-range, categorical-data, graphing

I have categorical data which are written every time there is a state change, the data in my case will have {state: ***, From: DateTime, To: DateTime}. The writing function also triggers every midnight, so no From-To will extend past midnight. My question is what is the most sensible way to graph this data? If possible I'd like to be able to graph it as shown in the attached image. If anyone has a better recommendation for graphing this or knows how to produce a graph like the one shown from a set of data I'd really appreciate the input.

For the language used to graph, if anyone knows of a C# extension, that would be ideal but for now any language that can give me something useable would be perfect.

Also I control the nature of the data, so if a solution requires fields to be added or changed, that's ok
[image: Graph Example]

Comment: Are you asking us to write that "extension" for you? Then I need to tell you that Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders *but you need to help yourself first. :-)* You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was hoping the extension already existed or that an extension existed for a similar one, I wasn’t expecting someone to make it for me haha @chade_